# Java look and feel at runtime different from jFrame preview (NetBeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-6.9

I am curious as to which I should trust what would best represent my code at runtime.
For example, when I build and run the application, I get the following: [image: Compiled version]

However, when I right click on my jFrame, and click on preview, I get what I actually "wanted" (I realize the menuBar is missing):
[image: Second image]

It's strange, because going into the Properties of the jPanel (which has the BorderedLayout manager and contains the jDesktopPane), and setting the preferred size or the size itself will actually 'refresh' and display accordingly whereas when I compiled and ran the program, no changes were visible.

So which should I trust?

Comment: In reality, neither. It will depend on how you've constructed your program to start, the preview is just that, a preview, which doesn't run your application code, but wraps the form within its window

Comment: Hmm that's unfortunate. It's just a bit frustrating because it seems that when I update my code, the preview is only affected rather than runtime.

Comment: Without a runnable example, it's really hard to provide advice